# Delete LiveData with Room onClick

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I have created a database using `LiveData` and `Room` following [google codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0) tutorial.

Problem is I am unable to delete an entry with `onClick`.
This is my **Dao**

```
@Dao
public interface PlacesDao {
  @Query("SELECT * from places_table ORDER BY place ASC")
  LiveData<List<Places>> getAllPlaces();
//  LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWords();


  @Insert
  void insert(Places places);

  @Query("DELETE FROM places_table")
  void deleteAll();

  @Delete
  void deletePlace(Places places);
}
```

And this is the **ViewModel**

```
public class PlacesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private PlacesRepository mRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Places>> mAllWords;

    public PlacesViewModel (Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PlacesRepository(application);
        mAllWords = mRepository.getAllPlaces();
    }

    LiveData<List<Places>> getAllWords() { return mAllWords; }

    public void insert(Places places) { mRepository.insert(places); }
}
```

and here is the **adapter**

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesAdapter.PlacesViewHolder> {

    class PlacesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView place;
        public TextView lati;
        public TextView longi;
        public ImageView delbutton;

        private PlacesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            place = itemView.findViewById(R.id.placeLine);
            longi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.longLine);
            lati = itemView.findViewById(R.id.latiLine);
            delbutton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delicon);
        }
    }

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Places> mPlaces; // Cached copy of words

    PlacesAdapter(Context context) { mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); }

    @Override
    public PlacesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.places_list_item, parent, false);
        return new PlacesViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlacesViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      Places current = mPlaces.get(position);
      holder.place.setText(current.getPlace());
      holder.lati.setText(current.getLati());
      holder.longi.setText(current.getLongi());
      holder.delbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          Snackbar.make(view, "DelButton Clisked", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          mPlaces.remove(position);
          Log.e("Adapter", String.valueOf(position));
        }
      });
    }

    void setPlaces(List<Places> places){
        mPlaces = places;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    // getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
    // mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mPlaces != null)
            return mPlaces.size();
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

I know its not good to do `onClickListner` inside BindView, but this is the closest I can go. 
On clicking the `delbutton`, both Snackber and Log is actvated, with `Log.e` is showing the expected value, but the item is not deleted.

So, can someone kindly help me on how to do that?

Regards,

**Update** The view is working, but I still cant delete rows from database. Any help please?

Comment: You removed from RecyclerView, but not from Database :)

Comment: Actually, its not even removed from the view.

Comment: Yes its because you removed item from your list, but you didn't notify adapter about the change :)

Comment: Ok. And how to actually delete the item from database? Is it ok to do this operation on BindViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick after remove just call `notifyItemRemoved(position);`.
And I suggest you to not use position in onClick, better use `holder.getAdapterPosition()`.